# What does "auch gar nicht gewesen" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Two girls talking about boys:

> ...
> – Und was macht mein Typ mit der Brille? Wo ist der denn hingegangen? Siehst du den irgendwo?
> – Nee, den kann ich nirgends entdecken.
> – Na ja, so interessant ist der **auch gar nicht gewesen**.

Source: *em Übungsgrammatik*

Comment: What is your problem with understanding this passage? Please take a look at [this FAQ](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628/2594).

Answer (score 0):

It is (Präsens)perfekt of "sein" with nice, hard to translate modal particles. I'd say that the most fitting translation is:

> He *just* was not *that* interesting.

"nicht" should be clear. "gar nicht" is "really not". "auch" means too, but here it puts emphasize on the fact that he wasn't interesting. I translated the modal particles with "just .. that".

Answer (score -1):

Dic.cc has a lot of Englisch-German equivalents for German gar. But "auch gar nicht" is lacking. Almost impossible to explain situations when you would use auch gar nicht. And I won't make an attempt to try it.

http://www.dict.cc/?s=auch+gar+nicht

Das war auch gar nicht meine Absicht!

I would translate: That wasn't my intention anyway!

But maybe there are better translations.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a relevant (colloquial) dictionary entry: (from [here](http://www.dict.cc/?s=auch%20nicht))

> so ... ist jd./etw. nun auch wieder nicht

may be translated as

> sb./sth. is not as ... as all that [coll.]

Hence, your sentence may be translated as

> Oh well, he was not as interesting as all that.

Would be nice if a native English speaker could confirm that this phrase is actually in use.

Here is more evidence for the existence of that phrase:

http://www.goenglish.com/Idioms/Bad+As+All+That.asp

http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g499573-d249339-r232735956-The_Lion_Hotel-Belper_Derbyshire_England.html

Comment: I'm not native English speaker, but your translation sounds awkward. I've never heard "as all that". I'd say "He was not all that interesting anyway".

Comment: Mind you, it is colloquial. Hence, the fact that you have not heard it does not mean it is not used. I provided some links, more evidence exists on google. Your translation has a similar meaning, but "that" corresponds to "so" in the German sentence, and the question is about "auch".